# IIS Rewrite Rule Clarification

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

Could someone please help me understand the difference when to use:

```
<match url="^$" /> vs. <match url=".*" />
```

Example:

```
<rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <conditions>
              <add input="{{HTTP_HOST}}" pattern="^(.+\.)?domain\.com\.au$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.new-domain.com.au/" />
          </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ^$ will match empty url
>
> .* will match any url empty or not .Will not match mulitiline url's though

[`Prevent Image Hotlinking`](http://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/)

Image Hotlinking is the use of an image from one site into a web page belonging to a second site. Unauthorized image hotlinking from your site increases bandwidth use, even though the site is not being viewed as intended. There are other concerns with image hotlinking, for example copyrights or usage of images in an inappropriate context.

With URL Rewrite Module, it is very easy to prevent image hotlinking. For example the following rewrite rule prevents hotlinking to all images on a web site http://ruslany.net:
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
<rule name="Prevent image hotlinking">  
<match url=".*\.(gif|jpg|png)$"/>  
<conditions>  
<add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />  
<add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^http://ruslany\.net/.*$" negate="true" />  
</conditions>  
<action type="Rewrite" url="/images/say_no_to_hotlinking.jpg" />  
</rule>
```

This rule will rewrite a request for any image file to /images/say_no_to_hotlinking.jpg only if the HTTP Referer header on the request is not empty and is not equal to the site’s domain.

Comment: Ok but what does it mean match empty URL and why we need this? Sorry for dumb  question.

Comment: thank you but the response still doesn't clarify what does match empty URL means. Would be good if you illustrate and example, perhaps.